# Missing documentation on "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not OK"

Tags: phpmyadmin, configuration-files

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not OK
Persistent favorite tables: Disabled**

Is the message I get when starting PHPmyAdmin 4.3.8.

1) This line has been added to config.inc.php

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';**

2) The table **pma__favorite** has been created.

3) In the documentation I cannot find information on what the content of the table should be. Nor can I find anything about: 
**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';**

So, what do I need to do to get rid of the message

**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not OK
Persistent favorite tables: Disabled**

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be missing from the documentation however you can find a reference to it in config.inc.sample.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
```

Copy and paste that into your config.inc.php. If you still have errors, the pma__favorite table was likely not created. It can be done either by importing examples/create_tables.sql or executing the following which I copied from there:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__favorite` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Favorite tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```