# MySql5.6 extended features listed as deactivated after being added

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

MySql5.6 Apache2.4 PHP5.6 win8.1

I imported and ran the script from **/examples/create_tables.sql**

phpmyadmin pma structure is now...

```
pma__bookmark
pma__central_columns    
pma__column_info
pma__designer_coords
<b>pma__favorite</b>
pma__history
pma__navigationhiding
pma__pdf_pages
pma__recent
pma__relation
pma__savedsearches
pma__table_coords
pma__table_info
pma__table_uiprefs
pma__tracking
pma__userconfig
pma__usergroups
pma__users
18 tables   Sum 2   InnoDB  utf8_bin    368 KiB 0 B
```

The storage database and tables section of my **config.ini.php** file is....

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
<b> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';</b>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
<b> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns'</b>
```

When I **start phpMyAdmin** I am getting...

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ... OK
General relation features: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   OK
Display Features: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ... OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    OK
Designer and creation of PDFs: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  OK
Displaying Column Comments: Enabled
Browser transformation: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    OK
Bookmarked SQL query: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  OK
SQL history: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ...   OK
Persistent recently used tables: Enabled
<b>$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ...  not OK
Persistent favorite tables: Disabled </b>
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ...    OK
Persistent tables' UI preferences: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ... OK
Tracking: Enabled 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ...   OK
User preferences: Enabled 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   OK
Configurable menus: Enabled 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... OK
Hide/show navigation items: Enabled
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ...    OK
Saving Query-By-Example searches: Enabled 
<b>$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] ...   not OK
Managing Central list of columns: Disabled</b>
```

If I comment out the lines in config.ini.php and restart the database I still get the message... "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated".

I have searched through the posts here and in other resources but could find no resolution for either **pma__central_columns** or **pma__favorite**

Can anyone provide a specific solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215684/missing-documentation-on-cfgserversifavorite-not-ok

Answer (score 5):

To fix the 'central-columns' issue do:

- add `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';` in file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` where `$cfg['Servers'][$i]...` is defined.
- load table data: `mysql -u{db-user} -p{db-pass} < /usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql/create_tables.sql`